# How to take the average for several columns while rolling up categorical column in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I have a data frame contains top 20 movies information without the movie name, and would like to roll up the data frame by taking the average of 4 columns: `runtime_min`, `imdb_rating`, `votes`, `gross_millions` while roll up other categorical columns `genre1`, and `year`. I'm not sure how can I do that all at the same time.

Here is the `dput` for the first 40 rows of the data frame:

```
top_20_movies <- structure(list(genre1 = c("Adventure", "Animation", "Comedy", 
"Comedy", "Comedy", "Drama", "Drama", "Adventure", "Drama", "Action", 
"Drama", "Crime", "Drama", "Comedy", "Adventure", "Adventure", 
"Biography", "Action", "Western", "Action", "Adventure", "Horror", 
"Adventure", "Comedy", "Action", "Comedy", "Adventure", "Drama", 
"Comedy", "Comedy", "Drama", "Drama", "Comedy", "Comedy", "Drama", 
"Drama", "Comedy", "Comedy", "Action", "Comedy"), runtime_min = c(212, 
75, 121, 124, 102, 125, 114, 136, 149, 141, 141, 160, 134, 120, 
132, 105, 180, 97, 122, 88, 126, 109, 197, 174, 208, 125, 162, 
109, 127, 91, 149, 146, 112, 180, 103, 126, 119, 104, 128, 91
), imdb_rating = c(8.1, 7.3, 8.2, 7.3, 7.5, 7.9, 7.6, 8.3, 7.6, 
8, 6.2, 8, 7.2, 6.3, 7.1, 4.4, 7.4, 7.1, 7.2, 6.6, 7.2, 8.5, 
7.9, 8.1, 6.8, 8.3, 6.9, 6.4, 6.6, 6, 6.7, 7.8, 6.5, 5.5, 6.8, 
7.1, 6.5, 6.6, 7.8, 6), votes = c(200456, 121718, 218547, 11149, 
13698, 13254, 12511, 269682, 8455, 50602, 2608, 53688, 10867, 
2123, 13885, 1747, 10978, 3862, 4740, 1023, 12168, 533018, 112656, 
58658, 8105, 142271, 13056, 5117, 18193, 731, 2246, 9227, 3598, 
746, 4001, 1947, 6009, 4055, 80449, 2711), gross_millions = c(74.7, 
51.6, 25, 23.3, 18.75, 13.99, 13.9, 13.28, 12.8, 12.54, 12.2, 
11.9, 11, 11, 10, 5.45, 5.01, 4.02, 3.71, 2.18, 40.36, 32, 30, 
19.52, 18.97, 18.6, 17.26, 16.46, 12.32, 12, 11.34, 11.34, 11.1, 
9.6, 7.4, 7.3, 6.54, 6, 4.91, 4.7), year = c(1959, 1959, 1959, 
1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 
1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1959, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 
1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 
1960, 1960, 1960, 1960)), row.names = c(51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 
110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L
), class = "data.frame")
```

and I'd like to achieve this type of result (please note all the average numbers in the result are made up numbers for now):

```
genre1    runtime_min  imdb_rating    votes     gross_millions    year
Action      102          8.1         123585        88.6           1959
Adventure    98          7.5          56868        56.2           1959
.....
Action       120          8.8         113685        101.5         1960
Adventure    108          6.3          25868        68.9          1960
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by `genre1` and `year` and then summarise all variables taking their mean

A tidyverse approach:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> top_20_movies %>%
    group_by(genre1, year) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean)
# A tibble: 13 x 6
# Groups:   genre1 [?]
   genre1     year runtime_min imdb_rating   votes gross_millions
   <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Action     1959        109.        7.23  18496.           6.25
 2 Action     1960        168         7.3   44277           11.9 
 3 Adventure  1959        146.        6.98 121442.          25.9 
 4 Adventure  1960        162.        7.33  45960           29.2 
 5 Animation  1959         75         7.3  121718           51.6 
 6 Biography  1959        180         7.4   10978            5.01
 7 Comedy     1959        117.        7.32  61379.          19.5 
 8 Comedy     1960        125.        6.68  26330.          11.2 
 9 Crime      1959        160         8     53688           11.9 
10 Drama      1959        133.        7.3    9539           12.8 
11 Drama      1960        127.        6.96   4508.          10.8 
12 Horror     1960        109         8.5  533018           32   
13 Western    1959        122         7.2    4740            3.71
```

An R base approach

```
aggregate(.~genre1+year, data=top_20_movies, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: this is awesome! Thank you.